# If the sample space is a set of possible outcome but not a set of sets, how would the sigma algebra generated by the sample space make sense?

Tags: probability

Sigma algebra is generated by the member of some power set. Sample space is a set of outcomes. They are not strictly the same thing. Why do we have the sigma algebra generated by the sample space?

Answer (score 1):

The sigma-algebra for a *probability space* is *a subset* of the *powerset of the sample space*; one which includes the sample space, and is closed under relative complementation, countable unions, and countable intersections.   (From the definition of sigma-algebra.)

In brief, the *sample space* is the set of all *possible outcomes*, while its *sigma-algebra* is a set of *measurable events*.   Those events are, of course, subsets of the sample space.

What else would we use?